# How to make a Spring WebFlow, Dojo (dijit) Text Field into a required TextArea

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

How can I change the following code to make the text field a textarea that is required and has the dijit text field look and feel?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>



<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 @import url("<c:url value="/resources/dojo/resources/dojo.css"/>");
 @import url("<c:url value="/resources/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>");
</style>     

<script djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/dojo/dojo.js"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring-Dojo.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC - Web Flow Example</title>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <h2>TextArea Test</h2>

    <form:form commandName="customer" id="customer">
        <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey"
            value="${flowExecutionKey}" />
        <div id="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><b>Bio:</b></td>
                    <td valign="top"><form:input path="bio" class="value" /> <script
                            type="text/javascript">
                        Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
                            elementId : "name",
                            widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox",
                            widgetAttrs : {
                                promptMessage : "Please enter your name from 2 to 10 characters",
                                invalidMessage : "A 2 to 10 characters value is required.",
                                required : true,
                                regExp : "^[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$"
                            }
                        }));
                    </script> <br />
                        <p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>

        <input type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration(
                                                {
                                                    elementId : 'submit',
                                                    widgetType : "dijit.form.Button",
                                                    widgetModule : "dijit.form.Button",
                                                    widgetAttrs : {
                                                        label: "Submit Page",
                                                        promptMessage : "Click here to submit page"
                                                    }

                                                }));
                            </script> 


        <script type="text/javascript">
            Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({
                elementId : 'submit',
                event : 'onclick'
            }));

        </script>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. see my answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962010/how-do-i-make-a-textarea-field-with-spring-webflow-and-dojodijit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it... its to add some code like this:

```
<form:textarea path="name" cssStyle="width:250px;height:15em" />
<script type="text/javascript">
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "name", widgetType: "dijit.form.Textarea", widgetAttrs: {value: ""}})); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "name", widgetType : "dijit.form.ValidationTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "Enter Description", required : true}})); </script>
```